# How to create tabs and make them show different lists on click (Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: xamarin.android, tabs, click

I have to make replica of the following screen:

[image]

When I click on `VIERNES, 05` tab I want a list to be shown below and when I click on `SABADO, 06` tab I want another list to be shown. But I want the transition from one list to another not to be made suddenly but gradually, as in the `gif` image above, by sliding (maybe it is made with fragments, I don't know). I want also the selected `tab` to change its style, the only difference I want is that it is underlined with blue color line, hex color :  `#007bc4` .My question is how do I create the tabs and make the functionality described above? I tried all from the first page of Google but nothing worked.

Comment: According to your description and screenshot, I search some info, and see that the Fresh Tabs may meet  your requirement:[Fresh Tabs in Xamarin.Android!](https://dev.to/fanmixco/fresh-tabs-in-xamarin-android-1cac)

Comment: These are icon tabs. I need the normal tabs with text as in the `gif` image of my question.

Comment: yes, you can add some TextView controls to replace ImageView in com.github.florent37.bubbletab.BubbleTab, you can try it.